# Set variables if they've not already been set as environment variables

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a suite of tests in node I want to run against a test environment.

When in development I want to run against localhost, however when running in a container I want to run against our test environment which is set via process.env variables.

Is there a way to set the host URL globally as localhost UNLESS it has been set as an environment variable?

I know I could probably write if statements checking if there is env variable set, however I was wondering if there was a best practise around this or a common strategy.

Thanks

Comment: I think https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv has some good explanations about how they encourage you to use their package, and why. The explanations there should hopefully give some direction in terms of convention.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if the env variable is available and if not set it to localhost. Example

```
if (!process.env.servicehost) {
    process.env.servicehost='localhost';
}
```

Would recommend that you encapsulate this into a method that returns a base service url. Example: `https://testhost.com/myApi` and then your test suites can connect to specific API paths. Use the above method to create this base service url in your startup phase.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any best practices here as what's best depends much on your development/production pipe-line.

One approach is to use the [`global`](https://devdocs.io/node~8_lts/globals#globals_global) object:

```
global.host = process.env.testhost || localhost;  // localhost already set to something
```

This will provide `localhost` if `testhost` is not defined.

Now `host` (or `global.host` if you prefer) is available to all modules.

Answer (score 1):

According Twelve-Factor Application principles the best way is store application config in environment variables not in application config or something like this, especially when you use Docker. Maybe you should use best from two options, i.e. like:

```
const URI = process.env.URI || 'localhost';
```